# How to move the window control buttons in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, window

I have recently updated Ubuntu to 18.04, and my window control buttons have changed from left to right (in user perspective).

Are there any ways to change it back to the way it was in 16.04 or earlier versions?

Comment: @pomsky that is for earlier version, i need a permanent solution for 18.04

Comment: Who said that won't work in 18.04? Have you tried any of the solutions at all? Run this command in Terminal: `gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'`.

Comment: FYI this doesn't work for me on 18.04. Gives an error message which can be fixed by adding `export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/` to .bashrc file. After adding the GIO_EXTRA_MODULES location the above command then works correctly. Per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934641/glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend-your-settings-will-not-b

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use GNOME Tweak Tool.

Install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

in the terminal. Or search for it in Ubuntu Software by typing gnome tweaks.

Go to **Windows** and look under **Titlebar Buttons**

[image: screenshot of GNOME Tweak Tool Windows menu]

Comment: this worked fine

Comment: Best answer so far